# Example of Camunda HTTP Connector to obtain array

Tags: camunda

I need to call REST-service which returns JSON like

{"listA":["A1","A2"], listB:["B1","B2","B3"]}

I want to do it using standard Camunda Service-task with http-connector

Can you give me an example of groovy|JS script for connectors Output Parameter that will than create some array variable in process instance (it further needs to be used in SubProcess collection variable)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
import static org.camunda.spin.Spin.*;
import static org.camunda.spin.DataFormats.*;

resp = connector.getVariable("response");
org.camunda.spin.json.SpinJsonNode json = JSON(resp);
 l = json.prop("List_A").elements();
ArrayList <String> ar = new ArrayList<String> ();
for (org.camunda.spin.json.SpinJsonNode n: l) {
    ar.add(n.stringValue());
}
ar
```